# Porque la fecha me sale 18/08/0006 si uso to_char('dd/mm/yyyy')

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo el siguiente query que realizo en mi consulta. Y por más que aplico:

```
to_char(FAI.INVOICE_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

o

```
to_char(FAI.INVOICE_DATE,'dd/mm/rrrr')
```

Le sigue saliendo la fecha `18/08/0006`

El query que uso es este:

```
                   nvl((SELECT to_char(FAI.INVOICE_DATE,'dd/mm/RRRR')
                             FROM FA_ASSET_INVOICES FAI
                            WHERE 1 = 1
                              AND FAI.ASSET_ID = FAB.ASSET_ID
                              AND NVL(FAI.INVOICE_LINE_TYPE, 'ITEM') =
                                  'ITEM'
                              AND NVL(FAI.FIXED_ASSETS_COST, 0) > 0
                              AND FAI.DATE_INEFFECTIVE IS NULL),
                   nvl(to_char(FBO.DATE_PLACED_IN_SERVICE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                       '')) CAMPO_C23
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a aplicarle el formato correcto para que salga correctamente

Comment: que tipo de campo es INVOICE_DATE?

Comment: ejecuta: `select to_char(sysdate,'DD/MM/RRRR') from dual` si te sale una cadena con el formato esperado, entonces podriamos suponer el tipo de campo que es invoice_date.

Comment: INVOICE_DATE es tipo Date

Comment: La respuesta más simple es que te sale ese valor, porque ese es el valor que está almacenado. De hecho, no encuentro otra explicación. Pero, veamos, ¿Qué te devuelve `extract(year from fai.invoice_date)`?

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar un dato de ejemplo y cuál es la salida que quieres obtener?